# Running Selenium and BrowserMobProxy on AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, browsermob-proxy

I am running headless chromedriver on AWS Lambda . Now I want to generate HAR file on lambda. So can anyone tell me how to generate har results / file on lambda . I tried to use BrowserMobProxy on lambda but getting the following error:-

> File "/var/task/browsermobproxy/server.py", line 134, in start
>       raise ProxyServerError("Can't connect to Browsermob-Proxy")
>   browsermobproxy.exceptions.ProxyServerError: Can't connect to Browsermob-Proxy

So if anyone can tell me about how to solve this error on aws lambda or if you have any other method to generate HAR results on aws using selenium .